# FCM errors using Firebase admin sdk and cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

Getting this error repeatedly. Error#1

```
    { Error: fcm.googleapis.com network timeout. Please try again.
    at FirebaseAppError.Error (native)
    at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:25:28)
    at new FirebaseAppError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:70:23)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/api-request.js:106:51)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:339:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
  errorInfo: 
   { code: 'app/network-timeout',
     message: 'fcm.googleapis.com network timeout. Please try again.' } }
```

Another error i get some times . Error #2

```
 { Error: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "read ECONNRESET".
    at FirebaseAppError.Error (native)
    at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:25:28)
    at new FirebaseAppError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:70:23)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/firebase-app.js:106:23
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:129:7)
  errorInfo: 
   { code: 'app/invalid-credential',
     message: 'Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "read ECONNRESET".' } }
```

One more type . Error #3

```
Error sending message: { Error: A network request error has occurred: read ECONNRESET
    at FirebaseAppError.Error (native)
    at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:25:28)
    at new FirebaseAppError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:70:23)
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/api-request.js:115:43)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:310:9)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1276:8)
  errorInfo: 
   { code: 'app/network-error',
     message: 'A network request error has occurred: read ECONNRESET' } }
```

What i'm trying to do with my cloud functions is check the users details, based on price match send FCM messages. The cloud function is a database trigger. Here is the code for my cloud function. I dont see any problems in the code as i'm using promises across.

```
// Checks price alerts for users
exports.priceAlertCheck = functions.database.ref('/crons/alerts/price').onWrite(event => {
  const promises = [];
  admin.database().ref(`/alerts/price`).once('value', function(alertSnapshot) {
    alertSnapshot.forEach(function(dataSnapshot) {
      promises.push(createPriceAlertPromise(dataSnapshot));
    });
  });
  return Promise.all(promises);
});

function createPriceUrl(fromCurrency, toCurrency, exchange) {
  return 'https://zzzz.com/data/price?fsym='
          +fromCurrency+'&tsyms='+toCurrency+(exchange ? '&e='+exchange : '');
}

function createPriceAlertPromise(snapshot) {
  const comboKeyArray = snapshot.key.split('-');
  const fromCurrency = comboKeyArray[0];
  const toCurrency = comboKeyArray[1];
  const exchange = comboKeyArray[2];
  return request(createPriceUrl(fromCurrency, toCurrency, exchange), function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        const jsonobj = JSON.parse(response.body);
        const currentPrice = jsonobj[toCurrency];
        const promises = [];

        snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
            promises.push(sendAlertNotifications(snapshot.key, data.key, currentPrice));
        });
        return Promise.all(promises);
      } else {
        console.log('Error fetching price', snapshot.key);
      }
  });
}

function sendAlertNotifications(comboKey, userId, currentPrice) {
  const getUserPromise = admin.database()
                          .ref(`/users/${userId}`)
                          .once('value');
  const getUserPriceAlertsPromise = admin.database()
                          .ref(`/user_alerts/price/${userId}`)
                          .once('value');
  return Promise.all([getUserPromise, getUserPriceAlertsPromise]).then(results => {
    const userSnapshot = results[0];
    if(!userSnapshot.val()){
      return console.log('Not user details', userId)
    }
    const instanceId = userSnapshot.val().instanceId;
    const subscriptionStatus = userSnapshot.val().subscriptionStatus;
    const priceAlertSnapshot = results[1];
    if(subscriptionStatus != 1){
      return console.log('Not Sending alerts. Subscription Expired', userId);
    }
    // Check if there are any device tokens.
    if (!priceAlertSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
      return console.log('There are no alerts to send for', comboKey, ", userId:", userId);
    }
    console.log("Alerts of users fetched for ", comboKey, " : ", priceAlertSnapshot.numChildren(), ", userId:", userId);
    const promises = [];
    priceAlertSnapshot.forEach(function(dataSnapshot) {
        promises.push(sendAlertNotification(userId, instanceId, currentPrice, dataSnapshot));
    });
    return Promise.all(promises);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("Error getting user alert details:", error, ", userId:", userId);
  });
}

function sendAlertNotification(userId, instanceId, currentPrice, dataSnapshot) {
  const comboKey = dataSnapshot.val().name;
  const comboKeyArray = comboKey.split('-');
  const fromCurrency = comboKeyArray[0];
  const toCurrency = comboKeyArray[1];
  const exchange = comboKeyArray[2];
  const alertPrice = dataSnapshot.val().value;
  if(priceAlertConditionCheck(currentPrice, dataSnapshot)) {
    // Notification details.
    const payload = {
      notification: {
        title: `${fromCurrency} Price Alert`,
        body: "You have been notified",
        sound: 'default',
        tag: comboKey
      },
      data: {
        title: `${fromCurrency} Price Alert`,
        body: "You have been notified",
        name: comboKey,
        sound: 'default',
        type: "alert"
      }
    };
    // Set the message as high priority and have it expire after 24 hours.
    var options = {
      priority: "high",
      timeToLive: 60 * 10
    };

    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(instanceId, payload, options).then(response => {
      response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
        const error = result.error;
        if (error) {
          console.error("Failure sending message:", error, " userId:", userId, " token:", instanceId);
        }
        console.log("Successfully sent message:", response, ", userId:", userId);
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("Error sending message:", error, " userId:", userId, " token:", instanceId);
    });
  }
  return;
}
```

Currently the data is small and still i'm getting 30% failures (10 to 15 records) in firebase database. How is this going to work when there are 10k records? How can i prevent these errors? Also there is no documentation for these error codes 'app/' but only for 'message/' errors.

UPDATE#1 : updated function :

```
function createPriceAlertPromise(snapshot) {
  const comboKeyArray = snapshot.key.split('-');
  const fromCurrency = comboKeyArray[0];
  const toCurrency = comboKeyArray[1];
  const exchange = comboKeyArray[2];
  return rp(createPriceUrl(fromCurrency, toCurrency, exchange),
  {resolveWithFullResponse: true}).then(response => {
    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
      const jsonobj = JSON.parse(response.body);
      const currentPrice = jsonobj[toCurrency];
      const promises = [];

      snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
          promises.push(sendAlertNotifications(snapshot.key, data.key, currentPrice));
      });
      return Promise.all(promises);
    }
    throw response.body;
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log('Error fetching price', error);
  });
}
```

UPDATE#2 : Increased the timeout of the function to 540 seconds but still getting the error#1

UPDATE#3 : updated functions : Error#1 is gone now but error#3 still exists and is happening more frequently

```
// Checks price alerts for users
exports.priceAlertCheck = functions.database.ref('/crons/alerts/price').onWrite(event => {
  return admin.database().ref(`/alerts/price`).once('value').then(alertSnapshot => {
    const promises = [];
    alertSnapshot.forEach(function(dataSnapshot) {
      promises.push(createPriceAlertPromise(dataSnapshot));
    });
    return Promise.all(promises).then(response => {
      return deleteFirebaseApp();
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      return logError(error);
    });
  });
});
function createPriceAlertPromise(snapshot) {
  const comboKeyArray = snapshot.key.split('-');
  const fromCurrency = comboKeyArray[0];
  const toCurrency = comboKeyArray[1];
  const exchange = comboKeyArray[2];
  return rp(createPriceUrl(fromCurrency, toCurrency, exchange),
  {resolveWithFullResponse: true}).then(response => {
    if (response.statusCode === 200) {
      const jsonobj = JSON.parse(response.body);
      const currentPrice = jsonobj[toCurrency];

      const forEachPromise =  new Promise(function(resolve) {
        const promises = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
          promises.push(sendAlertNotifications(snapshot.key, data.key, currentPrice));
        });
        resolve(promises);
      });

      forEachPromise.then(promises => {
        return Promise.all(promises);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return reportError(error, { type: 'database_query', context: 'forEach'});
      });
    } else {
      throw response.body;
    }
  }).catch(error => {
    return reportError(error, { type: 'http_request', context: 'price fetching'});
  });
}
```

Comment: What modules are you importing?  What does request() return (it appears you're assuming it returns a promise)?  If you're importing the module called "request" to get a hold of that request method, it's *not* returning a promise.  That means Cloud Functions is probably cleaning up before your request is complete, and killing off its connection.

Comment: const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
const request = require('request');
const express = require('express');

Comment: these are the modules i'm importing. Yes i was assuming request returns a promise. I have multiple database promise and http request promise combined together. What should i use?

Comment: Look into module request-promise which wraps request in a promise: https://github.com/request/request-promise

Comment: at the end of which function did you had to call `admin.delete()`? @1HaKr

Comment: Yes, call that fixed error#1

Answer (score 4):

Your code is using the node module `request` which does not deal with promises.  When dealing with Cloud Functions, it's usually easier to use a wrapper around that module called [request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise) which returns a promise so that you can react to the results of an HTTP request in a more useful way for code running in Cloud Functions.

Once you start returning valid promises from your function, Cloud Functions will wait for those requests to fully complete before cleaning up.  The ECONNRESET error is a symptom of it cleaning up too soon before your requests are complete.  I wrote about this a little bit in a [Firebase blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/06/keep-your-promises-when-using-cloud.html) recently.

Comment: Hey doug, i made changes and now i'm using request-promise module. Now im not getting error #2 and error #3 but i'm still getting error #1. I have updated the question with the new code

Comment: I don't know about that.  It looks like FCM is just not responding. I'd escalate that to Firebase support if you're still seeing that.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: Yes i have already contacted firebase support, waiting for a resolution from them.

Comment: hey @1HaKr you get a response from firebase support? or know what cause this error?

Comment: Yes they have told me to add admin.delete() at the end of the function as a work around

Comment: it turns out that I forgot to return a promise from the very first function. Once I return that promise chainsssss. No more timeout error! Thanks for it.

Answer (score 0):

Line 494:
    response.results.forEach((result, index) => {

Should be modified to:

return RSVP.all(response.results.map((result, index) => {

"forEach" returns null, which means that the promise actually resolves with null right away. "map" returns an array, and RSVP.all ensures that all of the promises in the array are resolved.

Currently, the function is getting killed before all the async tasks are done, that's why you're getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

I "solved" the issue by updating:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools@latest

npm install --save firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest firebase@latest
```